# Google_Service_Exception error 401 "Login Required" en Api google calendar

Tags: php, api, google-calendar

Quisiera su ayuda para un error que tengo al momento de crear un evento para el **google calendar** desde **php**, el error es el siguiente:

> { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required",
>   "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location":
>   "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }

Mi código esta así

```
    <?php 
                require_once 'xxx/xxx/googleApi/vendor/autoload.php';
                require_once 'xxx/xxx/googleApi/src/Google/Service/Google_Service_Calendar.php';

                $client = new Google_Client();
                $client->setAuthConfig('xxx/xxx/googleApi/client_secret.json');
                $client->setApplicationName("Name");
                $client->setAccessType('offline');
                $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/xxx/src/index.php?r=agenda/registrar');
                $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
                $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

                $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
                                    'summary' => 'Google I/O 2017',
                                    'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
                                    'description' => 'descripcion',
                                    'start' => array(
                                        'dateTime' => '2017-05-27T09:00:00-07:00',
                                        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
                                    ),
                                    'end' => array(
                                        'dateTime' => '2017-05-27T17:00:00-07:00',
                                        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
                                    ),
                                    'recurrence' => array(
                                        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
                                    ),
                                    'attendees' => array(
                                        array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
                                        array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
                                    ),
                                    'reminders' => array(
                                        'useDefault' => FALSE,
                                        'overrides' => array(
                                            array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                                            array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ));
                                $calendarId = ' xxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com';
                                $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
                                printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
?>
```

no sé en que falla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No veo que hayas generado el token de conexión:

```
// Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

Aquí puedes encontar un ejemplo que te ayudará a solucionar el problema.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Saludos,

Comment: Ya lo puse pero me sale un error más, sale esto 
Argument 2 passed to Google\Auth\Middleware\AuthTokenMiddleware::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\xxx\googleApi\src\Google\AuthHandler\Guzzle6AuthHandler.php on line 52 and defined